# AMazon Ec2 Instance error

Tags: amazon-ec2

please help on below. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNTOS.jpg)

Not able to copy - pscp to Amazon linux instance

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to transfer the file "key" to instance? using following:

```
pscp -i C:\Users\nuthalap\Desktop\Nagendra_Linux.ppk key root@ec2-34-210-110-111.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/new
```

If you want to transfer other file, e.g, following is transfer file c:\documents\foo.txt to your instance:

```
pscp -i C:\Users\nuthalap\Desktop\Nagendra_Linux.ppk c:\documents\foo.txt root@ec2-34-210-110-111.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/new
```